# XPATH : How can I extract the contents of the "value" attribute when the "name" attribute is Name?

Tags: xml, xpath

I've tried this XPath:

```
//root/title[@name="Name"]/@value
```

On this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<root>

<title name="Name" value="1"> Attribute extraction 
</title>

<title name="Local" value="1"> Attribute extraction
</title>

</root>
```

It doesn't seem to work as intended.  How can I extract the contents of the "value" attribute when the "name" attribute is Name?

Comment: What have you tried bro?  (HINT:  http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp)

Comment: I've tried this, doesn't seem to work as intended : //root/title[@name="Name"]/@value

Comment: It works for me.  It returns `1`.  Isn't that what you're expecting?

Comment: I have to parse this in a crazy app (a software beta), so it doesn't work like that. However this did the trick : //param[@name=”Name”]/@value. It looks like I have to go to the actual element that contains the attributes, so I have to skip all the parent elements. Thx anyway :)

Comment: This doesn't match your XML at all. Are you sure that the XML provided is the right one?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the value `1` instead of `value="1"` you can use:

```
string(//root/title[@name="Name"]/@value)
```